# How to convert an input line into a function?

Tags: python-3.x

How can i convert this piece of code into a function?

```
x = int(input('Please enter a positive integer: '))
```

I have tried

```
def user_input():
    x = int(input('Please enter a positive integer: '))
```

But it comes up with a undefined error.

Comment: which error comes up?

Comment: What's the full error? Seems it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign what you want to return to some random variable, you need to *explicitly return* it.

```
def user_input():
    return int(input('Please enter a positive integer: '))
```